# New table for every user?

Tags: mysql

I want to crate new table for each new user on the web site and I assume that there will be many users, I am sure that search performance will be good, but what is with maintenance??

It is MySQL which has no limit in number of tables.

Comment: Why would you want to create a new table for each user?

Comment: stick to a user table that has user_id, name, email, etc. And just make a primary key for your user_id so you can easily search for a user. If you make a table for each user, you'll end up with 100s of tables with only a few info in each. Waste of space and confusing

Comment: It also means giving the database user that the Web app logs in as the "create table" privilege.

Comment: @jpjp: It would also be slower

Comment: +1 for the question, so if somebody else gets the same idea, (s)he will be able to find out how bad this is much sooner ;-)

Comment: what about the case where each user has an appointments list? like 50 a week. if i store all the appointments in 1 table i'll have a zillion in months..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually tables are stored in a table too. So in this case you would move searching in a table of users to searching in the system tables for a table.

Performance AND maintainibility will suffer badly.

Answer (score 14):

This is not a good idea:

- The maximum number of tables is unlimited, but the table cache is finite in size, opening tables is expensive. In MyISAM, closing a table throws its keycache away. Performance will suck.
- When you need to change the schema, you will need to do one ALTER TABLE per user, which will be an unnecessary pain
- Searching for things for no particular user will involve a horrible UNION query between all or many users' tables
- It will be difficult to construct foreign key constraints correctly, as you won't  have a single table with all the user ids in any more

Why are you sure that performance will be good? Have you tested it?

Answer (score 12):

Why would you possibly want to do this? Just have one table for each thing that needs a table, and add a "user" column. Having a bunch of tables vs a bunch of rows isn't going to make your performance better.

Answer (score 5):

To give you a direct answer to your question: maintenance will lower your enthousiasm at the same rate that new users sign up for your site.
Not sure what language / framework you are using for your web site, but in this stage it is best to look up some small examples in that. Our guess is that in every example that you'll find, every new user gets one **record** in a table, not a **table** in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with option 1 (a table called tasks with a user_id foreign key) in the short run, assuming that a task can't have more than one user? If so then you'll need a JOIN table. Check into setting up an actual foreign key as well, this promotes referential integrity in the data itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).