# Make a SQL Table for every User of Website (thousands) with thousands of rows?

Tags: sql

We're building an eLearning MultipleChoice tool where thousands of users will complete our tests. We already have thousands of subscribers to our other seminars, etc, so it is very likely that thousands will also complete out MC-tests.

Now, we need to keep track of every question each user has answered, how long it took him, if it was correct (after how many tries) and if not, which wrong answer he gave, etc. Really a lot of data.

Now, we will have thousands of questions and thousands of users. Since every question will have at least 4 answers and we also want to track the wrong answers given, my question is: In this particular case, would it make sense to have a table per user?

I know the table-per-user question has been asked here already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940384/new-table-for-every-user), for example), but i feel like this is really a different case.

So: One table with millions of rows or thousands of tables with thousands of rows?

Comment: Who marked this down?  The OP is asking about options.  If you mark a question down because the OP wasn't correct in the first place, this would be a Wiki and not a Q&A forum.  Sheesh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It never makes sense to have a database object per user.  If you design your table and database structure appropriately, a table with a million rows is easily manageable.

A table-per-user will be very unmanageable, and that is not how relational databases are typically designed.

**Create one table for the users and adhere to RDBMS best practices.  Implement query tuning, and ensure there are appropriate indexes on the table, as well as updated statistics.**

Comment: +1 : With correct use of normalisation, primary and foreign keys, indexes, etc, you should never ever at all need a table per user.  Here's the corollary; would you ever need a new class per user in an OO language?

Answer (score 4):

The usual answer is that "table per user" is a horrible design, and the simple solution is a single table with an extra field(s) to identify ownership.

e.g. having

```
table_1   table_2    table_3 ...... table_999999999
id        id         id             id
...       ...        ...            ...
```

is a massive waste of resources, whereas having

```
table
id
user
...
```

is far easier to represent.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. So you would just add a column called "user" into the "one main table", put the user ID in there and then pop all the millions of rightly and wrongly answered question into one table? I'm still in the earliest planning-stages (started last week with Latex-Converters), so I'm still very flexible!;) Thanks!

Comment: You could have a table with fields something like this...  `UserID, TestID, QuestionID, SubmittedAnswerID, TimeSubmitted, ThinkingTime`.  Then all of your User information goes in one table, your Test information in another table, the list of questions in another table, the list of possible answers in another table, etc, etc.  If you separate everything out the Type of data, you're heading in the right direction.

Comment: Hey Dems! Thanks! I have the question/answer-tables set up like this: a table for questions, a table for answers (multiple per questionID) and one for explenations why the wrong answers are indeed wrong (connected by "answerid"). so now all i need is that "user"-table and i'm good, in your oppinion? also, would you put all questions into one table or have a table for each topic (which has about 30 tests each (and 30 questions each), and about 20 topics in all)? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Many RDMS let you create partitioned tables; I think that would be the best choice in your case (one partitioned table for all users; depends on RDMS you are using, you will have different options for specifying partition key)

Comment: We're planning on using MySql, so that should be possible on our server. I'll look into that option. It's good to hear such a definitive feedback from everyone. I guess I'll better go with the one-table-solution, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would deffinately not use one table per user, that would just get to be a nightmare to maintain.

If I were to try design that database I would probably attempt to break up the data as much as possible, so for instance you have:

Users table: Contains all your users
Questions : contains all questions

results: Contains all results
UserID, test_id, time

Test
testID, questionid, answers, time_to_complete

Answers
answer_id, answer

So in this scenario your Results table is an overview, it has the usersID, the test they took and the time to complete it, this is an overview of the whole thing.
Next you have the test table, this is the whole test the user took question by question, so you have id of the question, a link to a table with each answer the user submitted, and then time to complete it.
Answers table has each answer the user submitted

So the data would look like:

```
Results
UserID, TestID, Time
1         1      00:11

Test
TestID QuestionID, answers,  time_to_complete
 1      1              1         00:10:00
 1      2              2         00:01:00

Answers
answer_id, Answers
   1         A
   1         B 
   2         A
   3         A
   3         B 
   3         C
```

This approach would let you select specific data for each user, see how many times they have taken a test etc and it would be a lot easier to manage than thousands of tables.

Comment: hey purplegoldfish! thanks for this detailed answer. This sounds like a good way to go too. Just one question: in the "test"-table, I would also add the UserID, right? not nitpicking here, but I didn't quite understand if you would make a new test-table for every test being taken by every user (so if i take test 1, a table would be created and if i took it again a new table would be created, etc.) or if you would add all the results by all users of all tests into that table. Could you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: The Test table isnt probably named the best way, but the idea is that you have your user id in the results table then the test table links to the result table on TestID so you dont need a userID in there. You can probably figure out some more appropriate names for the tables but the idea is Results links to Test, Test links to Answers. Im not sure if you have predefined tests or just random questions but I figured I would call it Test just to show all the questions a user took in one session.