# Database design troubles. Table(s) for each user

Tags: php, mysql, security, codeigniter

First of all, I know the question has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940384/new-table-for-every-user) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796402/make-a-sql-table-for-every-user-of-website-thousands-with-thousands-of-rows) on stackoverflow. However this case might be different.

Let me explain the situation:

The boss wants me and my colleague to develop a web application where he can add customers (read companies, form now on 'user').
Each user will have it's own private section in the application where he can manage his stock/billing/payments/orders/... They even have the option to ask different modules/menu-items/views/.. for their private section.
Our boss must be able to add/remove some modules/views/.. by checking an option in the main control section.
And so on....

My first thought was to have a main module for each user. This idea was discarded by my colleague. He thought it was overkill.
But then, when we started to design the database, he said he wanted to have most tables in the database for each user...
I knew this was bad practice and tried to explain. **However he stated that it would be not secure if we saved everything in the same tables**. (*If we got hacked they would not only have one company it's data, but the data from ALL companies*)
The discussion took some time and in the end his '''point''' even convinced our boss of his method.

Since I'm the new guy here I don't like to stand firm on this without **knowing for sure** if `his statement === false`

So, I would love your opinions on this.

- How about security
- How about the personalization for each company
- How about managing the database
- Is there anyone who had a similar project
- How about using different 'modules' for each company (as in my first idea)
- ... (actually all info to convince them is fine, but I feel like I **must** come with a excellent alternative)

Thanks in advance

Comment: So let me get this clear, each user should get his own pair of equal tables to store it's data, which in general could be stored in on table distinguished with a userID per row?

Comment: I don't understand why would it be more secure with more tables. If you got hacked the whole database will be available for the hackers with every table. This just doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: Sounds like maintainabilty nightmare to me... Every little change would have to be applied to every single user-table. I don't know about security issues, but I guess if somebody can manage to compromise one table he will probably be able to compromise the whole database as well. From a database design perspective this sounds just wrong. Security should not be (such a big) part on a DB-design level. It's up to the application level to ensure a secure communication with the database.

Comment: This would be an awful database design. From a maintenance point of view, if you decide to add a column to the users' tables, you'd have to add it to all users' tables. Using security as an excuse for this bad design is not a valid argument - in general if you are hacked, the whole DB is compromised.

Comment: @complex857 nor to me.

Comment: That's one awesome application designer, let's have all users own their own tables and when project gets in such a mess that nothing can save it - off to a new job! Some people should just be prohibited from doing anything in IT.

Comment: @N.B. I've asked myself the question "why did I come to this company and not the other one" multiple times, and I only work here for 2 months now :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is to some extend a matter of personal oppinion. But some things just arent good practice. So here is my view on those points:

Having more than one "user" in the same table should not be a security risk at all.

- If someone has access to your db, he has all data, no matter what is stored where.
- Your app has to ensure via filtered and validated WHERE conditions that a user can only access his rows anyways or your app would have severe security issues on other levels up to SQL injections
- If you have one table for each user, you will have much trouble in scaleing your app to new users, manage old ones or delete them.
- Performance will be very bad if you ever have to collect data from more than one user
- There is a maximum number of tables in most DBs, depending on many factors. I dont know how many users you will have to store but keep this one in mind

The solution of seperating users into their own tables sounds like you are skipping the time needed to develop a solid and secure data model. This will usually lead to many problems during late development or maintenance of your app. I would strongly advice against that.

Rule of thumb should allways be to use a table per object type, not per object entity.

Comment: Thanks for your view on this. How about a case where you need to add fields for certain "users" only. Since this was a concern for my colleague I would like to know how to provide a solution for that

Comment: @Brainfeeder If you want to provide different fields/options/entries for each user or if you just want to provide the possibility to do so, you should abstract these things into another related table/data-model, e.g. user_table <--> user_options_table

Comment: That's my advice too. Make a user_id/key/value table and you can store whatever property you want. Those tables are also easily searchable over several properies. Only downside is that you have to pivot (collect all properties per user) yourself as most SQL tables do not have methods for this.
If you pivot yourself, do it in PHP and not in DB. PHP is very fast with it's array functions.

Comment: @Brainfeeder - on top of what Quasadunk and ToBe said - research EAV (entity-attribute-value) which is the model you'd use in your database to store user-specific values (it consists of entities like ToBe explained).

Comment: Good answer - but disagree with your second bullet point (which contradicts the first) - if your app is vulnerable to SQL injection then there are several other pre-conditions required for per-user tables to be of any advantage. A *further* point is that the multi-table approach adds a **lot** more complexity to the code - and complexity == insecurity.