# Is it a good idea?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, database, web

I have building a web for 3 weeks and I am in the database stage. I wanted to ask, is creating a table for each user a good idea? And if it is a good idea, how should I do that? Is there an option to create them in a folder named "users"? And also, is there an option of scanning them? like it is array?

Comment: Tomorrow you have 1 million users. What will you do?

Comment: Are you familiar with Excel (or some other worksheet tool)? Think of a database table like a work sheet (not workbook). Would you create 1 new worksheet for every user or would you create 1 sheet that contains all the users?

Comment: No, it is not a good idea

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940384/new-table-for-every-user

Comment: Bluntly put, it's not a good idea, it's a *terrible* idea. What problem are you trying to solve with having 1 table per user..?

Comment: Maybe this is worded a bit awkwardly. If you're aiming at multi-tenancy, then please try to reword your question along those lines and try to turn it into a programming question. If that's not possible, find another Stack Exchange site because it will be off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Create a user table and ingest the users along with a primary key. Also user credentials can be added, if column added for those in user table.